# Spring MVC: correct package for POJO used in services

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, pojo

I am developing an MVC application on Spring Boot, here is the structure of its packages:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Package 'domain' contains JPA entities and POJOs for Redis; package "repository" contains Spring Data repositories to work with domain model; package "services" contains service-layer and works with repositories; package "controller" contains REST controllers working with services.

But usually, services need to use some POJOs for service-specific data and pass it to controller. For example, the class FeedPage, which essentially POJO, aggregates the data, calculated FeedService and is not related to the database.

Could you please assist a right package for such POJOs: 
1) Store it in "domain" along with DB entites 
2) Store it  in services package ( services.feed)? 
3) Create package "model" under each service and store POJOs there

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon my old question.

Ended up adding a DOs classes into corresponding packages in the service layer where it's necessary. A naming convention for the DOs is `xxxDO` which let me easily notice such classes in a project tree.

Answer (score -1):

Create a folder called model under core. and use them for Data Transfer. These are POJOs are invariably named DTO or Data Transfer objects and would be best in their own package like model. There was a practice in SOA to have the data transfer objects in service specific folder but nowadays with Spring and package based AOP definition possibility, It would be better to have a seperate package for them.

Comment: Thanks for reply! What do you mean by "package based AOP definition possibility"

Comment: Also, seems now I use POJO from package "domain" as DTOs because they transfer data between DB<->Service Layer<->Controller. So "domain" package is something like "model" you've proposed. Would you recommend to move POJOs I asking about to package "domain" or still create a separate core.model pkg?

Comment: Try to use SPRING Data REST JPA which standardizes the package structure. 
If you would like to log metrics such as values or instance metrics , Spring AOP gives you the flexibility to define package level joinpoints.